# preg_replace with optional matches

Tags: php, preg-replace

Well.. i was creating a blog by myself and i've created a preg_replace for my "POSTS" then if i type:

```
[code="php"]foobar[!code]
```

he prints

```
<script type="syntaxhighlighter" class="brush: $1; html-script: true"><![CDATA[ foobar ]]></script>
```

everything runs OK with this preg_replace:

```
/\[code="(.*?)"\]/
```

(For prefix)

```
/\[!code\]/
```

(For sufix)

But now i want to add a additional option but check if user HAS TYPED... the idea is to be something like that:

```
[code="php" [1,3]]
foo
[!code]
```

return this:

```
<script type="syntaxhighlighter" class="brush: $1; highlight: [1,3]; html-script: true">...
```

otherwise if have not the $2 (user has typed only [code="php"]) return this:

```
<script type="syntaxhighlighter" class="brush: $1; html-script: true">
```

How can i create this statement in same preg_replace? Thanks in advance and sry for the bad english.

**EDIT**

I've achieved my solution with *preg_replace_callback*

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need to use 2 separate calls for this. Don't think you'll manage it with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use preg_replace_callback to do what you want:

```
function format_prefix($matches)
{
    return '<script type="syntaxhighlighter" class="brush: '
        . $matches[1]
        . (isset($matches[2]) ? '; highlight: ' . $matches[2] : '')
        . '; html-script: true">';
}

$s = '[code="php"]foobar[!code]'."\n".'[code="php" [1,3]]foobar[!code]';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\[code="(.*?)"(?:\s+(\[\d+,\d+\]))?\]/', 'format_prefix', $s);
```